# Synonymize [ssdt] and [sql-server-data-tools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) is the abbreviation of [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools). Can we make them synonyms?

Although [SSDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSDT) can stand for some other computer related topics, all of the [ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) questions on SO are about SQL Server Data Tools.

[image]

Comment: In the areas I work, SSDT is ["System Service Dispatch Table"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Service_Dispatch_Table). I didn't even know there was a related SQL topic.

Comment: Can moderators or gold badge user approve a synonym even if it is not getting necessary score? why a similar case is not getting approved until now?