# Can moderators or gold badge user approve a synonym even if it is not getting necessary score

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Can moderators or gold badge user approve a synonym even if it is not getting necessary score? why a similar case is not getting approved until now? The synonym provided is so clear *([ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) is an abbreviation of [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools))*

- [Synonymize [ssdt] and [sql-server-data-tools]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275084/synonymize-ssdt-and-sql-server-data-tools)
- [Expedite Tag Synonym approval for [sql-update] and [sql-server-data-tools] and [dts]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347701/expedite-tag-synonym-approval-for-sql-update-and-sql-server-data-tools-and)

Comment: [For context - how synonyms work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/175248)

Comment: @Makoto this is clear, and i know it. but what i am is why like this synonym suggestion are not approved even if there are related meta posts and they are so clear.

Comment: Again...the link even explains that.  Raising awareness is pretty much what you can do; gold badge holders have no power here, and moderators have their hands full with other stuff (and *likely* wouldn't approve a synonym that the community could, even eventually).

Comment: @Makoto it is not a good thing to have two tags [tag:ssdt] and [tag:sql-server-data-tools] and there are the same!!

Comment: I have no dog in this fight.  I'm merely stating how the protocol works.  Coincidentally, you're at least raising its profile so users of those tags that also frequent Meta could do something about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gold tag badge holders *cannot* unilaterally approve a synonym. This is not one of the powers granted by the gold tag badge. All they can do is vote for the synonym. It takes 4 votes for it to be approved, and voting requires a score of 5 in the applicable tag. It's a hard row to hoe for some of the lesser-used tags, especially since >99% of our users don't even know about the [Tag Synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) page.

However, moderators *can* unilaterally approve (and suggest) a synonym for any tag in the system.

The problem is that the tooling around tag synonyms... leaves a lot to be desired. Because of a variety of circumstances (Flag Overflow™, lack of community consensus, and insufficient expertise), moderators have historically not been very active in creating synonyms. I plan to change that, because the tag system is in need of some serious love. It'll still be far from a perfect system, especially because nothing has changed regarding how difficult it is to judge when community consensus is reached on a Meta question, but I am going to do what I can to get useful synonyms in place at the behest of the community.

I wish there was a better way to go about this than a bunch of individual Meta retag questions, but I don't know what it is yet. Even though I'm committed to this, I need people who are experts in the tags to tell me what synonyms are reasonable and others to counsel caution where there are unforeseen problems.

Comment: A review queue maybe? The same goes for deletion/undeletion votes, I see no way to see them other than run into a flagged question by chance.

Comment: @ivan https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms is essentially already a review queue. And delete/undelete are in [the 10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools).

Comment: No, it's not. It's not in the review interface, and there are no review items (with possible "request declined" result and all), or a streamlined interface! You can't possibly expect me to regularly visit several hard-to-reach pages, can you. Especially if I can't even readily see the results as net stats.